# Can´t join a list the way I would like

Tags: python

In this code:

```
lista = []
número = int(input("Introduce números que se añadirán a una lista, cuando termines escribe un 0: "))
while número != 0:
    lista.append(número)
    número = int(input("Introduce otro número: "))
x = "<".join(str(sorted(lista)))
print(x)
```

The output is:

```
Introduce otro número: 6
Introduce otro número: 1
Introduce otro número: 8
Introduce otro número: 2
Introduce otro número: 0
[<1<,< <2<,< <3<,< <6<,< <8<]
```

Why I don´t obtain `1<2<3<6<8` in this code ? I think it has to do with the string format. If I do type for every element in the list the output is str. But then if after the while I do the following it works fine:

```
second_list = [str(x) for x in (sorted(lista))] 
print("<".join(second_list))
```

I just don´t really understand why the one in the image doesn´t work.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show code, output and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: An alternative would be to leave the numbers as strings, converting them to `int`s *only* for the purpose of sorting. `x = "<".join(sorted(lista, key=int))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` converts the `list` into its string representation. Use `map` to convert each number in the `list` to `str`:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,9,5]
print("<".join(map(str, sorted(lista))))
>>> 1<2<3<4<5<9
```